# Showing all open windows in main page WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

We have an application developed in WPF. i wanted to implement one functionality here. From main page, Main page has quick links to all child windows. if i open 20 windows, i wanted to see all the opened windows listed on mainpage. My main page is blank now so i can show in any way possible. Does WPF has this functionality??? please help

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`Application.Current.Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx). You can enumerate and show them in your main-window.

Answer (score 1):

Keep them all in an `ObservableCollection<Window>`, then use a `ListView` or such to display them. Style your `ItemTemplate` at wish.